# batch script: remove subfolders that do not contain a certain

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to figure out a win command line to remove all subfolder that do NOT contain *.nes and redirect output to a log file.

Comment: Do not contain \*.nes *where*? In the folder name? Filename(s) inside the folder? What should happen if the folder contains subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

This will delete any sub folder in the folder where the batch script is located that does not have a file with .nes ending inside it (anywhere even in sub sub folders). Be careful with this script it can not be easily undone if you test is carelessly. It does not warn when run.

```
@echo off
:: do not use if you don't know 
:: what you are doing!
::
:: this file deletes all subfolders 
:: without files with *.nes in them
:: WARNING: use with extreme care!



echo --- cleanup on %date% %time:~0,-3%% --- >> removed.log

for /D %%i in (*) do (
    dir /b /s ".\%%i\*.nes" >NUL 2>NUL
    if errorlevel 1 ( :: dir sets errorlevel 1 if no file is found
        rmdir /q /s "%%i"
        echo.    removed %%i >> removed.log
    )

    set errorlevel=0
)

echo. >> removed.log
```